# Encryption in iphone and decryption in php

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I want to encrypt the sound in objective c (iPhone), so that i can send it to web server, after sending the php automatically decrypt the file. Is there any way, kindly help me...

I have sound in NSData variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone SDK includes the [Security Framework](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004330), this library includes many common crypto functions.

If you're a little more specific I can help you out with a high level implementation.

Comment: Kindly help me for some specific algorithm which I can implement at both php and objective c end.

Comment: Could you let me know at least the nature of the encryption, will you just want to protect something during transport? Do you want to store some encrypted data in a database?

Comment: Actually I am sending the sound data from iphone, which is receive on web server. PHP script save the sound in to some specific directory. Now I want to encrypt the sound at iPhone end and Decrypt at php end, after decryption it store into some specific directory. I have already implemented the AES-128 bit encryption algorithm, but I am not be able to get the specific result. Kindly help me.

Comment: Sounds like you just need encryption during transit, if that's the case I would recommend just using HTTPS(SSL). You'll need a certificate for your site, but I believe that those are reasonably priced now.
If this is not an app that you're selling you *can* install a certificate to your iPhone/iPod Touch by e-mailing it to yourself then opening it from the Mail app.

If you'd really rather use AES128 then I'd recommend either implementing a key-exchange(more secure), or storing a key file on the device and the web server(less secure).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will try to follow your instructions.